# Using bquote() to print confidence intervals

Tags: r, plot

I want to use the function `bquote()` in `R` to put a confidence interval on a graph.  I am able to get the first parenthesis and number, but everything after that is problematic.

For example if I wanted to print the following confidence interval (2,5) then I have the following:

```
plot(1:5)
lower = 2
upper = 5
mtext(bquote("("~.(lower)))
```

that gets me half the interval but I can't get the rest of it. I would have thought something like

```
mtext(bquote("("~.(lower),","~.(upper),")")
```

would have worked, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `as.expression` to coerce the whole thing into an expression and use `*` to separate variables from strings

```
plot(1:5)
lower = 2
upper = 5
mtext(as.expression(bquote("("*.(lower)*","*.(upper)*")")))
```